# Add background on last col-sm and will be on right

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can add a fake background color on last `col-sm` and that well be on right side. Bootstrap grid system.
For example:

[image: the background color layout I want]

And the blue background well be responsive, and full on right side.
I try fixed fake container, absolute but doesn't work well.

Answer (score 1):

you can try css.

```
#last-bar {
  border-right: 60px solid #42bcd7;
  padding-right: 30px !important;
}
```

give id 'last-bar' to the last div.